# Visual Studio 2008 and Wine

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wine

Anyone have tried to run Visual Studio 2008 over linux wit wine? Any troubles? It works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WineHQ has some [test results](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=11022&iTestingId=21512) on this subject, which seems to give a firm *no*. However, as you can see they are somewhat outdated. You could always try yourself with the most recent version and post on Wine forums for help, though I suspect you're begging for pain and trouble.

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago I tried to run the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor under Wine, and had to hack in several implementations of missing Wine APIs before it would work.  Given that, what are the chances that the full thing will work?  Not good.

Comment: I guess I will use a Virtual OS !